# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "lstm_14" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 4)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, normalization

So I am developing a classification model using LSTM for a custom protein dataset with Keras. I've been using this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv) to normalize the data using the Normalization layer they talk about in it. However, when I compile the model I get `ValueError: Input 0 of layer "lstm_15" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 4)`

The code I have so far:

```
protein_features = protein_dataset.copy()
protein_labels = protein_features.pop('Class')
protein_dataset = np.array(protein_features)
normalize = layers.Normalization()
normalize.adapt(protein_features)


model = Sequential([
   normalize, 
   layers.LSTM(50, return_sequences=True),
   layers.Dropout(0.5),
   layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
   ])

model.summary()
```

protein_feautres array shape, taken from a CSV dataframe:

```
array([[14.    ,  0.42857143,  0.        ,  0.83333333],
   [17.        ,  0.35294118,  0.551     ,  0.8       ],
   [25.        ,  0.36      ,  2.999     ,  0.78571429],
   ...,
   [35.        ,  0.05714286,  1.615     ,  0.        ],
   [21.        ,  0.14285714,  1.644     ,  0.        ],
   [14.        ,  0.        ,  1.244     ,  0.        ]])
```

Comment: Do you understand that LSTMs process sequences, and you seem not to have sequence data?

Comment: No, I didn't know that,  I'm pretty new to DL. I was testing different architectures, which architectures would you recommend to train on tabular data? @Dr.Snoopy